# any way to make this command chain shorter or better

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, grep, command-substitution

I am using this command chain to filter out bot/crawler traffic and ban the ip addresses. Is there any way i can make this command chain more efficient?

```
sudo awk -F' - |\\"' '{print $1, $7}' access.log | 
grep -i -E 'bot|crawler' | 
grep -i -v -E 'google|yahoo|bing|msn|ask|aol|duckduckgo' | 
awk '{system("sudo ufw deny from "$1" to any")}'
```

Here is a sample log file i am parsing. The default apache2 access.log

```
173.239.53.9 - - [09/Oct/2019:01:52:39 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 3955 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.6.01001)"
46.229.168.143 - - [09/Oct/2019:01:54:56 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 4084 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/6~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
157.55.39.20 - - [09/Oct/2019:01:56:10 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 3918 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
65.132.59.34 - - [09/Oct/2019:01:56:53 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 4150 "-" "Gigabot (1.1 1.2)"
198.204.244.90 - - [09/Oct/2019:01:58:23 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 4480 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.8; http://mj12bot.com/)"
192.151.157.210 - - [09/Oct/2019:02:03:41 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 4480 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.8; http://mj12bot.com/)"
93.158.161.112 - - [09/Oct/2019:02:09:35 +0000] "GET /neighborhood/ballard/robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 31379 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
203.133.169.54 - - [09/Oct/2019:02:09:43 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 4281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Daum/4.1; +http://cs.daum.net/faq/15/4118.html?faqId=28966)"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show at least a few lines of your input file `access.log` in your question.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, AWK can do everything `grep` can, and you shouldn’t need multiple AWK invocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a single `awk` command:

```
awk -F' - |\"' 'tolower($7) ~ /bot|crawler/ && tolower($7) !~ /google|yahoo|bing|msn|ask|aol|duckduckgo/{system("sudo ufw deny from "$1" to any")}' access.log
```

This will filter out only entries that have `bot` or `crawler` in the 7th column (what your first `grep` command does.  **Only if** the 7th column **does not** contain `google|yahoo|bing|msn|ask|aol|duckduckgo` (what your second `grep` command does).  Any matching line will have `sudo ufw deny from "$1" to any` executed on it's first column.  (What your final `awk` command does).